# /var/spool/mail point to ../mail and /var/mail point to /var/spool/mail is this something wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, email

I just noticed that

```
/var/spool/mail is a symlink to ../mail
```

and

```
/var/mail is a symlink to /var/spool/mail
```

so its infinite symlink situation here ;)

can anyone tell me if this is expected behaviour?

Because in my opinion its not. But I'm not a unix GURU.

if there is something wrong with it can anyone help me to solve it please?

The system is **Ubuntu Server 12.04** and I have also postfix/dovecot which uses the **/var/vmail** for virtual email accounts

Comment: its just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, it is broken.
On 12.04

/var/spool/mail is symlink to /var/mail

/var/mail should be a regular directory with root:mail ownership.